# gnu radio - bit rate

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have propably very stupid/simple question to GnuRadio users.

I have a Random Source as a source of bits [-1, 1]. And I want to multiply every bit with cosinus to make bpsk modulator. 
Problem is that Bits are generated as fast as possible... (dont have enything in common with samp_rate). When I have 1 period of cosinus, there are generated many bits from Random Source.

Question is, how can I slow down bit rate generation ??

Thanks for any help
[image]

(I dont want to use DPSK Mod :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can not delay the generation of bits. However you can increase the duration of each symbol. This can be done with the `repeat` block of GNU Radio. This block takes a parameter called `interpolation` that corresponds to the number of times an input item will be repeated at the output.

So you find the period of your cosine in samples, lets say `p`. For each random bit produced by the `Random source` block, you repeated it `p` times with the `repeat` block. With this way you increase the duration of your random symbol. Then you pass the resulting samples to the `multiply` block of your flowgraph.

Comment: yes this is what I wanted to find. I tried with Rational Resampler but that block was distorting my signal. thank you

Comment: Rational re-sampler performs filtering too, that why your signal got distorted.

Comment: But it was distorted even when my Interpolation/Decimation was 1:1 .... so I dont get it.